# How to use Primefaces Extensions InputNumber with String

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I am using [Primefaces Extensions](http://primefaces-extensions.github.com/) 3.20 with [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) 5.2.11 running in a Weblogic 10.3.6. I tried to use [inputNumber](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/inputNumber.jsf) to refer to a String property. However, when I submitted the page, I got a `null` String from this field. Just when the inputNumber came to refer to a numeric property (such as a Long), I got a value. Apparently the inputNumber component works just with numbers.

Does someone know a way how to use inputNumber with Strings?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: will http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml help?

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar, actually this was my solution (or workraound). However, for me, the ideal would be use inputNumber.

Comment: sorry. then you would have to build your own component. Just use these as building blocks https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/tree/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component/inputnumber